# Socket not receiving from the client

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

```
int main()
{
    CRc5 dec;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int err;
    if((err =WSAStartup(0x0002, &wsaData)) !=0)
    {
        printf("Init WSAStartup() failed[%d].", err);
        return false;
    }
    //socket structure
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;//addr = socket structure
    int addrlen = sizeof(addr);

    //making the socket
    SOCKET sListen;//listenig to the incoming connections
    SOCKET sConnect;//operating the connection

    //setuping the socket
    sConnect=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);//sock_stream = that the socket is a connection_oriented

    //setup the structure
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");// ip of the connection
    addr.sin_family= AF_INET;
    //seting the prot
    addr.sin_port= htons(9958);

    //sertuping Listen socket
    sListen=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);
    //binding connection
    bind(sListen,(SOCKADDR*)&addr,sizeof(addr));
    //listening 
    listen(sListen,SOMAXCONN);//listing with out any limit
    printf("Attempting Socket Connection\n");
    printf("Wating For An Incoming Connection!\n");
    for(;;)
    {
        if((sConnect=accept(sListen,(SOCKADDR*)&addr,&addrlen)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            char buf[500];
            int len = strlen(buf);
            recv(sConnect,buf,len,0);

        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error accepting %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
        }
    }
}
```

but it's not receiving anything it's accepting the socket from the game client and then nothing happend why!!?

Comment: Can you put the game client code where you are connecting the socket and then writing the buffer to the socket

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ recv() problem](/q/4840535/90527)

Answer (score 1):

```
         char buf[500];
         int len = strlen(buf);
         recv(sConnect,buf,len,0);
```

The `strlen(buf)` is clearly an error. Don't know if that is the reason that `recv()` doesn't work, but you should definately use `sizeof(buf)` instead.

You should also know that `recv(socket, buf, 500, 0)` will not necessarily receive 500 bytes, even if 500 bytes are sent by the sender. It might receive only 1 byte or any number *up to* 500.

Also it won't necessarily receive everything that the sender sends with a single `send()` call. A socket is purely a stream and there are no message borders.

I'm just mentioning those two things since they are the "number one mistakes" beginners make with sockets.

Comment: Can anyome tell me why stackoverflow listed this question on the front page today? I cannot see any recent activity, except for my answer. Of course this is not a problem, I'm just curious. 2 months are a rather long time, chances that the answer will still help the OP are rather slim I suppose.

Comment: just as pgroke seid recv function only receives as much data as is ready to read(but will wait if there is none) if you know the package size your client is sending you can use this `recv(socket, buf, packageSize, MSG_WAITALL)` but it will stop your app until either the connection is intrupted or all the package is recieved

Comment: Unfortunately `MSG_WAITALL` isn't 100% portable. E.g. Windows versions up to and including XP don't support it.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    if((sConnect=accept(sListen,(SOCKADDR*)&addr,&addrlen)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        char buf[500];
        int len = strlen(buf);
        recv(sConnect,buf,len,0);

    }
```

You should probably not re-use `addr` to find the address of incoming connections. There might not be anything *wrong* with it, but knowing that you used the same variable for two different things in your program gets harder the larger your program grows. Give each variable a specific task and only reuse variables with very good reason.

But the problem is most likely that `strlen(buf)` call. Nothing has zeroed the `char buf[500]` that you allocated on the stack. Your `strlen()` may return `0`, if there was a `0` byte sitting in that location by accident, or it may return `2000`, if that's how many bytes it has to look through before finding a `0` byte. (I'd guess something like `12` would be common. :) You could use `sizeof buf;`, but that can be brittle if you change your mind down the road and allocate the array using `malloc`. So just use a constant for both the length in the allocation and the `recv()` call. It'll be harder to miss that when you decide to make it dynamic in the future.

Comment: /i did what u said about the variable but it's not the prob, the prob is  when it's come to recv(sConnect,buf,len,0); it's like stop continuing so there is nothing will be add to buf or buflen , coz when it's come to recv the program stop continuing!!

Comment: @MixedCoder, I assumed you had data waiting for `recv()`. If you don't (i.e., you're writing an application rather than a toy :) then you need to choose one of two paths: either (a) use non-blocking sockets and a tool like `select(2)` to multiplex among the sockets (look into [libevent](http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/) to make this easier!) or (b) use separate threads, one per client, to allow yourself to use the simpler blocking networking primitives. Threading introduces new ways for programs to break, so it would be my second choice, but it is sometimes best for specific cases.

Comment: your strlen() is a very wrong thing to put here. The important point is, recv() will block until it reads the specified number of bytes. And the number of bytes you pass is basically garbage. If your client writes 10 bytes and you ask for 12, you'll stay there for ever. Of, and don't forget to check for return value of recv.

Comment: @Arkadiy, `recv(2)` will _not_ block until the requested amount is available: `The receive calls normally return any data
       available, up to the requested amount, rather than waiting
       for receipt of the full amount requested.`